# Fonts added as resource don't work in some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

I've been trying to add a font as a resource in my Android project and I followed the steps needed to it: created a "`font`" directory in my "`res`" dir, copied my `.ttf` files into it and created a `myfont_fontFamily.xml`, where I defined both `app:` and `android:` `fontStyle`, `fontWeight` and `font`.

I've been testing the code in 2 phones: a Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 and a Samsung S9. In the case of the S9 and the design preview of Android Studio, the fonts work (both in the case where I set the `android:fontFamily= "@font/myfont_fontFamily"` (refering to myfont_fontFamily.xml), or the `.ttf` file I want to use as a font directly (e.g. `android:fontFamily= "@font/oswald_bold"` for the file `oswald_bold.ttf`)). But in the Xiaomi Note4, none seem to work...

Keep in mind that I've tried https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml solution and other solutions extensively but none seemed to work.

Any advice on how to get the font I want to work in all devices? Thanks in advance!

Comment: won't lie, we've been having font issues for a long time now, company has a specific font they use and it seems to render terribly on certain devices, so i hope you find a good answer at least :D

Comment: No solution seems to work for any custom font, even when added directly from Google Fonts UI for font families in Android Studio. Tried many of the most used fonts (Montserat, Roboto, Oswald, HelveticaNeue,..) and no luck on this device. Any possible solutions I could try? Also, tried to change the font programmatically and had the same outcome...

Comment: no clue, fonts are giving us a hard time too, hope you find an answer